# Reference related object with annotate in django

Tags: python, html, django, postgresql, django-queryset

Having a bit of a struggle with what seems like it should be a simple issue...

Essentially I have some sites where counts of objects occurred over several years:

Example:

```
site_id = Site1: (Year:2012,Count:133), (Year:2011, Count:150), (Year:2010, Count :110)
site_id = Site2: (Year:2010, Count:300), (Year:2010, Count 333)
```

Data are temporally patchy (not regular - some sites were counted some years.. others not...).. also, sometimes those places were counted a couple of times a year

What I want to do is get the LATEST count for each site, and IF there was more than one count, I want to get the HIGHEST count..
Then I want to display that in HTML.

here is my MODELS.PY

```
class Counts(models.Model):
    count_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    site = models.ForeignKey('Site', blank=True, null=True)
    year = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    count = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'counts'


class Site(models.Model):
    site_id = models.TextField(primary_key=True)
    site_code = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    site_name = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'site'
```

This is the Query I am trying to use in VIEWS.PY

```
p = ['Site1','Site2']  ## Just for reference for the example... values come from a POST or a GET

A = Site.objects.filter(site_id__in = p).annotate(latest=Max('counts__year'))

context = RequestContext(request, {'dat':A})
template = loader.get_template('styles/searchResults.html')        
return HttpResponse(template.render(context))
```

The above gives me only the latest years:

```
[{'site_id': u'Site1','latest': 2012}, {'site_id': u'Site2','latest': 2010}]
```

What I want is:

```
[{'site_id': u'Site1','latest': 2012,'count':133}, {'site_id': u'Site2','latest': 2010,'count':333}]
```

But - I want it as a QuerySet (not a ValuesQuerySet) because I want to reference it in my HTML template like this:

```
<table>
{% for x in dat %}
    <tr><td>{{x.count|floatformat}}</td><td>{{x.year}}</tr>
{%endfor%}
</table>
```

I have tried the following (after creating A from above):
    B = Counts.objects.filter(year__in = A.values('latest'),site__site_id__in = p).annotate(site_code=Max('site__site_id'))

But this results in essentially:

```
[{'site_id': u'Site1','latest': 2012,'count':133},{'site_id': u'Site1','latest': 2010,'count':110}, {'site_id': u'Site2','latest': 2010,'count':333},{'site_id': u'Site2','latest': 2010,'count':300}]
```

In other words, it is pulling out all values where YEAR = 2010 OR 2012 for both sites.

Again, what I'm looking for is the HIGHEST count for the LATEST `year. Max(count), Max(year)` - I'm sure that plays in somehow...

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about ordering by year and count and using .distinct() to take only the first record for each site?

```
A = Counts.objects.filter(site_id__in = p).order_by('site_id','-year','-count').distinct('site_id')
```

If you need the corresponding site info this is accessible in the template

```
<table>
{% for x in dat %}
    <tr><td>{{x.count|floatformat}}</td><td>{{x.year}}</td><td>{{x.site.site_name}}</td></tr>
{%endfor%}
</table>
```

or use .values() specifying the values you want from each model in the view. The result *is* iterable in a template too.

Comment: Thanks for this - actually very very close to what I need - this returns MOSTLY what I need. I just need to take this one step further to also get out the site_name and site_code (from the Site model)

Comment: adding .select_related() to the above results in each count object having its corresponding site object as an attribute, with site_name and site_code available through that in the template. So A[0].site.site_name would return the site name. select_related stops the need for an extra db hit, but the site is already available anyway

Answer (score 1):

Edited:

Though the below answer worked for me, I was concerned about performance...
So I have re-hashed based on user5219763 - much cleaner now...

<strike>I have tinkered around and found this works...</strike>

```
from itertools import chain

### First create an empty list to push querysets
qlist = []
### Iterate through each selected ID 
for x in p:
    ### Find the value for the latest year for each site id selected
    A = Site.objects.filter(site_id = x).aggregate(Max('counts__year'))['counts__year__max']
    if A:
        ### Find value of the highest count for year identified above for the selected site
        B = Counts.objects.filter(year = A, site__site_id=x).aggregate(Max('count'))['count__max']
        ### Now, resample the Site where the year is the max and count is max, then annotate the queryset
        ### with the values from year and count in the Counts table...
        C = Site.objects.filter(counts__year=A,counts__count=B).annotate(year = Max('counts__year'), count = Max('counts__count'))
        ### push this query to the list
        qlist.append(C)
    else:
        continue
            ### use itertools chain command to merge these into a single queryset
qs = list(chain.from_iterable(qlist))
```

Now I'm using:

```
qs = Counts.objects.filter(site__site_id__in = p).order_by('site__site_id','-year','-count').distinct('site__site_id').select_related()
```

Then, in my HTML I reference it like this:

```
{% for x in dat %}
    <tr ><td>{{ x.site.site_name }}</td><td>{{x.site.site_code}}</td><td>{{x.count|floatformat}}</td><td>{{x.year}}</td></tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Thanks, folks!

Comment: Answer: good. Additional questions IN the answer, though - those are unlikely to be seen or responded to, because that's not how things work here.  If you have a NEW question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](//stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button.

Answer (score 0):

There are two solutions with `QuerySet` and `ValuesQuerySet`.

**1. QuerySet**

Not recommended for large `Site` and `Counts` tables, because of the performance -- for each site you will get an additional query to fetch a latest object of `Counts`(complexity `O(N*M)`). But it's ok if there are small count of rows. For example:

*View*

```
A = Site.objects.filter(site_id__in=p).annotate(latest=Max('counts_set__year'))

# Fetch latest Counts for each Site object
for site in A:
   site.counts_latest = site.counts_set.order_by('-year').first()
```

*Template*

```
<table>
{% for x in dat %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{x.counts_latest.count|floatformat}}</td>
        <td>{{x.counts_latest.year}}</td>
    </tr>
{%endfor%}
</table>
```

That's all!

**2. ValuesQuerySet**

You should put in `values` list of all `Counts` fields, which can be used in template. For example:

*View*

```
A = Site.objects.values('counts_set__count', 'counts_set__year') \
        .filter(site_id__in=p).annotate(latest=Max('counts_set__year'))
```

*Template*

```
<table>
{% for x in dat %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{x.counts_set__count|floatformat}}</td>
        <td>{{x.counts_set__year}}</td>
    </tr>
{%endfor%}
</table>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi Albert - thanks for your advice. However. the ValuesQuerySet code you provided simply lists every year.  "[{'counts__year': None, 'counts__count': None, 'latest': None}, {'counts__year': 1994, 'counts__count': 807.0, 'latest': 1994}, etc.... Also, this creates a ValuesQuerySet, which can't be iterated through as you have described in the template.  QuerySets work, but ValuesQuerySets not so much.